# Getting larger mathematics

Tags: fonts, size

I'm trying to make a (very) large poster, and need correspondingly large text and mathematics.

Unfortunately it seems like by default, LaTeX has a maximum font size. Increasing the value of `\scaling` in the following minimum working example does nothing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\scaling}
\setlength{\scaling}{2.2pt}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{24.88\scaling}{30\scaling}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
asdf $asdf \epsilon$
\end{document}
```

Playing with this a bit, I can increase the font size of just the non-mathematical text by adding `\usepackage{palatino}` to the preamble. But nothing I try increases the size of the mathematics.

Searching this sends me down a rabbit hole on using `\DeclareMathSizes` (to no effect), or of trying to install some other font package. (All of them large, confusing, and lacking installation instructions.)

I'm more or less at my wit's end. I don't even care what font I end up using, I just want larger text and mathematics!

Comment: you can use fix-cm package to get larger fonts in cm (or switch to more or less any other font set such as lmodern, which allow all sizes by default) but often for a poster it is simpler to design it at a smaller size, say A4 or A3 then just scale up the PDF to A0 or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is 200pt size sufficient? The following has that size on A0 paper.

```latex
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a0paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixcmex}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{200}{240}\selectfont

Some text
\[
\sum_{k=0}^n k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `fix-cm` we make Computer Modern fonts fully scalable; this wouldn't affect the math extension font, for which `fixcmex` does the job.

Alteratively, use a font that's already fully scalable.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a0paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % Palatino clone

\begin{document}

\fontsize{200}{240}\selectfont

Some text
\[
\sum_{k=0}^n k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing, thankyou! The fix was just to add `\usepackage{fix-cm}` (or equivalently `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}`).

Comment: I bow to excellence and remove my answer.

Comment: (Moot point now, but regarding the suggestion for `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}` - I'd already tried that but didn't already have them installed, and `newpx` was what I was referring to about being confusing and lacking installation instructions!)

Comment: Unfortunately the text is rather too close to the math.  It would be a good idea to increase the above/below displayskips to compensate.

Comment: The RHS of the equation should read n(n+1)/2 ;)

Comment: @user94293 Oops!